# Mysterious white line between page contents

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I am making a slide transition between whole pages and everything is fine except one thing: the line between pages

[image: Mysterious line between 2 pages]

For transition I use `translateY` property. Interesting thing happened when I tried to use top property instead - there was no line between contents. Anyone knows how to fix it because I would not like to use top prop.

**Demo:** https://wallet.itb1704.tautar.ee/main

Comment: Is this public anywhere ? Or else, edit your question with relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Niloct oh yes, my bad.. https://wallet.itb1704.tautar.ee/main , click on the first button and you will see

Comment: Difficult to help without seeing the code since it's Vue but in the browser I was able to remove the line by adding the following classes to the main HTML tag `bg bg-gradient-to-r from-green-999 via-blue-999 to-purple-999` this of course means the page would not be white to start with, but you could conditionally apply those classes to the HTML tag during transitions.

Comment: @JHeth yeah, I understand that code would be better for you to see the whole picture but I am just not sure what exactly you need :/

Comment: In your case a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could just be 2 solid color slides with a button to transition back and forth between them. It would mean duplicating your project and removing all your content and anything not related to the transition where the problem is occurring. If you can show the white space in a simplified version then it can be solved much easier.

Comment: JHeth idk man.. I have cleaned the project and did not find anything that could create a line... Actually, I thought that it would be pretty easy for css gurus just to guess where is the problem, but whatever. As my upper page has white block on the top, I will just leave a bottom: -1px on the page.